# travis failing for R BioC packages using new LATEX format

Tags: r, latex, bioconductor

I have a Bioconductor package and we are moving to the last version to compile vignettes and I getting a error of a missing style font during travis: `beramono.sty`:

https://travis-ci.org/lpantano/isomiRs

The package that creates the vignette is BiocStyle and they introduced this dependency:

https://github.com/Bioconductor/BiocStyle/search?utf8=✓&q=beramono&type=

I tried to install that missing file in my travis but it seems that is not working. Do you have any advice to install that font?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I found this in the docs where you can install latex packages: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#LaTeX-TexLive-Packages. Trying this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to .travis.yml fixed:

`before_install:
  - tlmgr install bera
  - tlmgr install nowidow
  - tlmgr install parnotes
  - tlmgr install marginfix`

Answer (score 0):

Try `texlive-fonts-extra` per

```
$ locate beramono
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beramono.sty
$ dpkg -S $(locate beramono) 
texlive-fonts-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beramono.sty
$
```

Or skip building vignettes which is what I do at Travis ...

Comment: thanks!. I have this in the travis file:`before_install:  - sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` but didn't fix it. Maybe should go in other section. I guess skipping vignettes is a way to avoid this right now.